# Rails: call controller action with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a link_to that I want to call a background action before rendering the page.  I thought I could do this by calling the controller and action within the link_to, but it doesn't seem to be doing anything (I put a debug log in the controller to see if the action was being called, and nothing is being printed to the console).

**view:**

```
        <%= link_to 'Back', project_step_path(@project, @steps.count-1), `{:controller=>:steps, :action=> 'destroyNewImages'}, :class => "btn btn-small" %>
```

**controller:**

```
  # Destroy new images
  def destroyNewImages
    logger.debug("-------testdestroy------");
  end
```

How can I call a controller action from within a link_to?

Comment: It's not very apparent why you need something to run in the background before rendering your page. Do you need to run this task and have it block your page from loading?

Any additional information about your use case would be helpful here.

Comment: What about a `destroy_new_images` route in your `config/routes.rb` file directing to your action. You could then link to the `destroy_new_images_path`. If nescessary, nest it as a collection or member action under your projects resource. [A great general resource on Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for some reading.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I have a form where users can upload images, which are saved as new objects; if the user presses back instead of saving the form, then I need to delete the images from my model.